# Calling the php function from javascript function using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a class named "Example" and has following methods
`printProduct(),printCategory()`. The `printProduct` has an anchor tag which has call to javascript function through onclick and using Ajax I call a PHP page where I pass the value of current product.

```
private function _printProductLinks ($value_selected) {
        $html = "";
        $html .= "<ul class=\"tabs\">";
        for($i=0; $i<count($this->_productArray); $i++) {
            if($this->_productArray[$i]->_productId == $value_selected) {
                $html .= "<li><a onclick=\"gotoProduct(".$this->_productArray[$i]->_productId.")\" id=\"selected\">" .$this->_productArray[$i]->_productName."</a></li>";

            }else {
                $html .= "<li><a onclick=\"gotoProduct(".$this->_productArray[$i]->_productId.")\">" .$this->_productArray[$i]->_productName."</a></li>";
            }
        }
        $html .= "</ul>";
        return $html;
    }

private function _printCategoryLinks () {
        $html = "";
        $html .= "<ul class=\"tabs\">";
        for($i=0; $i<count($this->_categoryArray); $i++) {
            if($this->_categoryArray[$i]->_categoryId == $this->_currentCategory) {
                $html .= $this->return_nbsp(2)."<li><a onclick=\"gotoCategory(".$this->_currentProduct.",".$this->_categoryArray[$i]->_categoryId.")\" id=\"selected\">" .$this->_categoryArray[$i]->_categoryName."</a></li>";

            }else {
                $html .= $this->return_nbsp(2)."<li><a onclick=\"gotoCategory(".$this->_currentProduct.",".$this->_categoryArray[$i]->_categoryId.")\">" .$this->_categoryArray[$i]->_categoryName."</a></li>";
            }
        }
        $html .= "</ul>";
        $html .= $this->_printSubCategoryLinks();
        return $html;
    }
```

and the javascript `gotoProduct()` is as follows

```
function gotoProduct(product_id){
    try{
        var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
        var jsonstring = "product=" +encodeURIComponent(product_id);
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "dp_entry.php", true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", jsonstring.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
               // var jsondata = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.send(jsonstring);
    } catch (e){
        alert("Can't connect to server:\n" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

so,on executing the `printProductlinks()` will call javascript function `gotoproduct(product_id)` and then has to print the categories using `_printcategories()` under the products

Comment: I'm confused. What was the question exactly?

Comment: After executing the gotoProduct() the printCategoryLinks() should get executed.

Comment: god damnit, provide some PHP and JS code, we can't know what you're doing just like that ...

Comment: Where does printCategoryLinks() get called? Inside dp_entry.php? If so then we need to see that as well

Comment: That is php function should be called from javascript function gotoproduct()